# Is there an easy way to expand/complete a pandas DataFrame to include missing observations with multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
    'category1': list('AABAAB'),
    'category2': list('xyxxyx'),
    'year': [2000, 2000, 2000, 2002, 2002, 2002],
    'value': [0, 1, 0, 4, 3, 4]
})

>>> df
  category1 category2  year  value
0         A         x  2000      0
1         A         y  2000      1
2         B         x  2000      0
3         A         x  2002      4
4         A         y  2002      3
5         B         x  2002      4
```

I'd like to expand the data to include missing years in a range. For example, if the range were `range(2000, 2003)`, the expanded DataFrame should look like this:

```
  category1 category2  year  value
0         A         x  2000    0.0
1         A         y  2000    1.0
2         B         x  2000    0.0
3         A         x  2001    NaN
4         A         y  2001    NaN
5         B         x  2001    NaN
6         A         x  2002    4.0
7         A         y  2002    3.0
8         B         x  2002    4.0
```

I have tried an approach using `pd.MultiIndex.from_product`, but that creates rows that aren't valid combinations of `category1` and `category2` (for example, `B` and `y` shouldn't go together). Using `from_product` and then filtering is too slow for my actual data, which includes many more combinations.

Is there an easier solution to this that can scale well?

---

**Edit**

This is the solution I ended up going with, trying to generalize the problem a bit:

```
id_cols = ['category1', 'category2']

df_out = (df.pivot_table(index=id_cols, values='value', columns='year')
            .reindex(columns=range(2000, 2003))
            .stack(dropna=False)
            .sort_index(level=-1)
            .reset_index(name='value'))

  category1 category2  year  value
0         A         x  2000    0.0
1         A         y  2000    1.0
2         B         x  2000    0.0
3         A         x  2001    NaN
4         A         y  2001    NaN
5         B         x  2001    NaN
6         A         x  2002    4.0
7         A         y  2002    3.0
8         B         x  2002    4.0
```

Comment: The verb for filling in missing observations, with reference to existing data, is "impute".  With simply a `NaN`, you're facing a combinatoric problem.  Please post your attack as the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let us do `stack` and `unstack`

```
dfout=df.set_index(['year','category1','category2']).\
         value.unstack(level=0).\
         reindex(columns=range(2000,2003)).\
         stack(dropna=False).to_frame('value').\
         sort_index(level=2).reset_index()
  category1 category2  year  value
0         A         x  2000    0.0
1         A         y  2000    1.0
2         B         x  2000    0.0
3         A         x  2001    NaN
4         A         y  2001    NaN
5         B         x  2001    NaN
6         A         x  2002    4.0
7         A         y  2002    3.0
8         B         x  2002    4.0
```

Comment: can we replace `df.set_index(['year','category1','category2']).value.unstack(level=0)` with `df.pivot_table(index=['category1,'category2'],values=['value'],columns=['year'])`?

Comment: @Ch3steRC yes we can ~

Comment: Thanks for responding. Is `set_index([...]).value.unstack` faster than `df.pivot_table(...)`?

Comment: @Ch3steRC same method to reshape the df ~ for large df pivot_table should slightly faster than unstack

Answer (score 2):

```
#create a separate dataframe and merge with df to get your new form
a = ('A','x',range(2000,2003))
b = ('A','y',range(2000,2003))
c = ('B','x',range(2000,2003))

from itertools import product, chain
res = ((product(*ent)) for ent in (a,b,c))
columns = ['category1','category2','year']
fake = pd.DataFrame(chain.from_iterable(res),columns=columns)
fake.merge(df,on=columns,how='left').sort_values('year',ignore_index=True)

category1   category2   year    value
0   A   x   2000    0.0
1   A   y   2000    1.0
2   B   x   2000    0.0
3   A   x   2001    NaN
4   A   y   2001    NaN
5   B   x   2001    NaN
6   A   x   2002    4.0
7   A   y   2002    3.0
8   B   x   2002    4.0
```

alternatively :

```
fake = df.drop_duplicates(['category1','category2']).filter(['category1','category2'])

fake.index = [2001]*len(fake)
#merge two indexes on year    
pd.concat((df.set_index('year'),fake)).sort_index()
```

### Update

You can abstract the process by using the [complete](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.complete.complete) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/):

```
# pip install pyjanitor
import janitor

df.complete(
        ("category1", "category2"),
        {"year": [2000, 2001, 2002]},
        sort = True
)

  category1 category2   year    value
0   A           x       2000    0.0
1   A           x       2001    NaN
2   A           x       2002    4.0
3   A           y       2000    1.0
4   A           y       2001    NaN
5   A           y       2002    3.0
6   B           x       2000    0.0
7   B           x       2001    NaN
8   B           x       2002    4.0
```